# How to fix: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in BoneCP

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, bonecp

I'm working from [this](http://jolbox.com/jdbc-example.html) example and I am running into this error after adding log4j, slf4j and bonecp to the project:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/FinalizableReferenceQueue
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:321)
    at javasampleapps.BoneCPExample.main(BoneCPExample.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.FinalizableReferenceQueue
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 2 more
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to BoneCP and SLF4J, you need to add [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), because [BoneCP's requirements page](http://jolbox.com/requirements.html) states that it needs to be present. Download `guava-*.jar` and add it to your classpath the same way you did with SLF4J and BoneCP.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add those jars to the classpath of your Java process when you run it. For example,

```
java -classpath lib/log4j.jar;lib/slf4j.jar;lib/bonecp.jar [your_class]
```

This assumes that the jars are in a dir called lib which is in the directory you execute the Java command from.

Comment: I added them to the libraries section of my project? Doesn't it add it to the classpath upon doing that?

Comment: Your IDE may add them to your build classpath automatically. Depending on how you execute Java, you may have to add them to your runtime classpath yourself.

Comment: It turned out to be guava that I hadn't added. Thanks.